# Invite users to view nodes that are hidden from public.

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using the [question](http://drupal.org/project/question) module on my Drupal 7.x website and I want some specific people to answer that.
Node_invite and rsvp modules only have a 6.x version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Node Access Password](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_password) or the [Access Links](https://drupal.org/project/access_links) modules. These allow for node access by using a password and a path alias respectively.

Notice that you should uncheck the permission of "**View published content**" from all kind of user roles and of course from anonymous users.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).